# Adding two single linked list in C while data from the first will end up only in odd indexes

Tags: c, list, function, sum

I'm looking for a help with writing a function in C.
Function must be able to sum two linked lists while the elements from the first list must end up only in odd indexes of the 3rd list, and the elements of the 2nd list must end up only in even indexes (obviously :D). Thanks in advance.

So the code looks like this:

```
#define NAME_SIZE 20

#define SURNAME_NAME_SIZE 20

typedef struct employee {

    char    name[NAME_SIZE];
    char    surname[SURNAME_NAME_SIZE];
    float   experience;
    struct  employee *next;
} employee;

typedef struct EmployeeList {

    employee* tail;  // Pointer to last element in list
    int         size;   // Number of elements in list
} EmployeeList;
```

This is the example of a main function:

```
int main(void){

    EmployeeList list1;
    EmployeeList list2;
    EmployeeList merged;
    employee e1 = {"Johnnie","Walker",90};
    employee e2 = {"Jack","Daniels",80};
    employee e3 = {"Johnny","Depp",95};

    employee e4 = {"Jim","Jimmy",23};
    employee e5 = {"Kate","Kim",32};
    employee e6 = {"Mary","Jane",46};


    EmployeeListCreate(&list1);
    EmployeeListCreate(&list2);
    EmployeeListCreate(&merged);

    EmployeeListInsert(&list1, &e1, 0);
    EmployeeListInsert(&list1, &e2, 1);
    EmployeeListInsert(&list1, &e3, 2);

    EmployeeListInsert(&list2, &e4, 0);
    EmployeeListInsert(&list2, &e5, 1);
    EmployeeListInsert(&list2, &e6, 2);
```

Output - merged list should look like:

```
"Johnnie","Walker",90

"Jim","Jimmy",23

"Jack","Daniels",80

"Kate","Kim",32

"Johnny","Depp",95

"Mary","Jane",46
```

Comment: Ok? So you iterate over your first two lists, to create the third  calling `EmployeeListInsert` on the first pointer in list1, then add on the first pointer in list2, then advance to the next node in each and repeat?

Comment: 1) Why are you using such a complex data type, when you could develop this function using lists of `int`? 2) What have you tried?

Comment: What happens if one list is longer than the other?